# Trying to automate contact deletion with SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, automationstudio, gdpr

with the GDPR laws in place, it's important to have the possibility to remove contacts from Marketing Cloud. I'm trying to automate the process with existing tools and am looking for possible solutions.

Right now I'm trying to use the [Remove() function](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_subscriberRemove.htm) from the Subscriber Object in the Core SSJS library:

```
<script runat="server">
    Platform.Load("Core","1");

    var subObj = Subscriber.Init("000-T-01-API-Delete");
    var status = subObj.Remove();

</script>
```

The contact was created manually in Mobile Connect and exists in All Contacts. Although the query completes without errors, the contact remains in the system.

Any idea how to fix the script to perform the deletion?

I am thinking this might not be the best approach since it would be a 1 by 1 deletion of contacts performed in a loop, but I don't see an option like the API allows to tell the system to delete contacts stored in a data extension.

Any advice or ideas how to automate this process would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Updated March 2020 to accomodate for v2 authorisation and tenant specific endpoints.**

Please see the example of how I use this for bulk deletion. You should use the REST API, using the [DeleteByListReference endpoint](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/DeleteByListReference.htm). Here it works together with a sendable DE, and SSJS activity in Automation Studio:

```html
<script runat="server">
    Platform.Load("Core", "1");
    //AUTHENTICATE
    var url = "https://[yoursubdomain].auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/token";
    var contentType = "application/json";
    var payload =
        '{"grant_type": "client_credentials","client_id": "[YOURID]","client_secret": "[YOURSECRET]","account_id":"[YOURMID]"}';

    var accessTokenResult = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, payload);
    var accessToken = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(accessTokenResult["Response"][0]).access_token;

    if (accessToken != "") {
        //EXECUTE
        try {
            var deleteUrl =
                "https://[yoursubdomain].rest.marketingcloudapis.com/contacts/v1/contacts/actions/delete?type=listReference";
            var payload1 =
                '{"deleteOperationType": "ContactAndAttributes","targetList": {"listType": {"listTypeID": 3},"listKey": "[Data Extension External Key]"},"deleteListWhenCompleted": false,"deleteListContentsWhenCompleted": false}';
            var headerNames = ["Authorization"];
            var s1 = "Bearer ";
            var headerValues = [s1.concat(accessToken)];
            var result = HTTP.Post(deleteUrl, contentType, payload1, headerNames, headerValues);
        } catch (ex) {
            Write("Exception Error: " + Stringify(ex));
        }
    }
</script>
```

Remember to have the Data Extension created as sendable, and the only column required is the Subscriber Key. Also do ensure that Contact Deletion is enabled on your account. [Here is how you do it.](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_contact_deletion.htm&type=5)

**Warning**: When deleting contacts using the GDPR functionality you will render the SDKs unable to communicate with the Marketing Cloud servers. You need to be very, very careful to ensure that you're not deleting contacts that are still valid.

Additional details on [Marketing Cloud Contact Deletion can be found here](https://digitalmarketingoncloud.com/salesforce-marketing-cloud/contact-deletion-in-marketing-cloud/).

Comment: Lukas,
I'm extremely grateful for this answer. It's really a great piece of code for someone like me that's just learning to use the API and scripts in Automation Studio.

With proper deletion settings (suppression period set to 0) the contact is already gone from the system :)

Thank you so much!

Comment: Please find here a more detailed code with error handling  by @adamspriggs https://gist.github.com/wvpv/b6ccea822efc424fbad2739a53308fbc#file-cnx18-rasa-contact-delete-js

Comment: @zeljazouli, thank you for that link. The code looks great.

Comment: @Lukas this is great. It ran successfully for me, but did not actually delete the contacts. Does it only work at the parent MID?

Comment: Yes, @garek007 - you need to run it in root BU. Also, it might take up to days or even weeks, depending on the volume of contacts and data extensions in your account

Comment: @Lukas, does this SSJS also delete contacts from Sales Cloud (if we have a connector and using contact ID as Subscriber key) or it will only delete a contact from the Marketing cloud?

Comment: @Sohail - this will only delete the contact from MC. In a cross cloud scenario, you will need to delete the contact from SC first, or at least prevent it from being synced.

Comment: With the script, the interesting part is the contact is deleted from MC. And contact does exist in the Sales cloud and it didn't sync back to MC on the next schedule sync. I am just wondering why it didn't sync back???

Comment: Hi @LukasLunow, I am debugging a Contact Delete script that used to work in the past, but now I noticed there is a problem with passing the accessToken in the contact delete payload. I stumbled to into this thread now and was wondering what is the logic behind this? `var s1 = "Bearer "; var headerValues = [s1.concat(accessToken)];` Thanks!

Comment: Hi @zuzannamj - As per [this doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/DeleteByListReference.htm) you need to pass the token value prepended with "Bearer " in Authorization header. The line you quoted just appends token to the "Bearer " string.

Comment: Thanks @LukasLunow - I always used `var headerValues = [“Bearer “ + accessToken];` but now neither this nor your concat works for me. Thanks!

Comment: Hey @LukasLunow thanks for the answer. I have one small question. we have more than 1M records to remove. Can I override contacts, with another 1M, in DE I used as reference to remove contacts? I suppose/hope that SF makes some sort of copy so the DE can be removed right away.

Comment: Yes, @MarcelGentSimonis - once the SSJS has been executed and deletion process has started, you can overwrite the referenced DE with a new set of Contact Keys

Comment: @LukasLunow thanks.. just one last. deletion process is to be executed with lowest priority. I wanted to know if the reference is made right after the SSJS executes this API call. Basically i want to run this every hour and the keys will be replaced in each run.

Comment: @Marcel - that will not be a problem

Comment: Hi, Lukas. Thanks for the solution. But when I use your code it runs well for token API. If it gets hit for the next API, it returns a Bad request error. I think the "var payload1" is the reason but I could not able to find out the error. Tried so many ways but failed. Can you please provide any suggestions? Followed this:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ZzywRPvjBo  Also tried your github code but not worked! @LukasLunow

Comment: @NurUddin Did you replace the values in the payload, to match your external key of the data extension? Also, did you ensure this is a sendable data extension?

Comment: ` var deleteUrl = "https://mcctldtq61xcp.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/contacts/v1/contacts/actions/delete?type=listReference";
       var payload1 ='{"deleteOperationType": "ContactAndAttributes","targetList": {"listType": {"listTypeID": 3},"listKey": "EC0F33-E73D-46C6-B865-D5461046C"},"deleteListWhenCompleted": false,"deleteListContentsWhenCompleted": true}';`  @LukasLunow

Comment: I tested the api using postman, it worked. But in SSJS it returns `The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.` @LukasLunow

Comment: @NurUddin Well - if it works from Postman, then there is nothing wrong with the payload or the URL. Please reach out to support to see, if they can provide you with more info from the API error logs.

Comment: https://ibb.co/94MW07q Can you please whole code? the commented API by contact key is working, I think there must be an inconsistency in payload! @LukasLunow

Comment: @NurUddin - are you running this SSJS in your root business unit? Also, is the MID in your token request the same as the MID where you are running this code?

Comment: 1. Maybe 2. Yes, Is there any changes to be made if run API from child unit? @LukasLunow

Comment: @NurUddin - you need to authenticate your call to the root (EID) business unit. This is the MID you need to put in your token request. Also, the data extension should be accessible in that business unit. However I suspect this might not be the issue, since as you say, the request is working fine from Postman. There is only so much I can do to help you, and I will recommend to reach out to Salesforce support to identify any additional issues.

Comment: Yes, you are right. As `delete?type=keys` works well this one should work as well. How can I reach them out? Any link or way? @LukasLunow

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140092/discussion-between-lukas-lunow-and-nur-uddin).