# How to delete All contact under contact builder in marketing cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, subscriber

We have bulk contact approx 1 million and we want to delete these all contacts from the marketing cloud so how we can delete these contacts from marketing cloud?

Answer (score 1):

You can delete up to 1 million contacts per operation.

[Contact delete best practices](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_best_practices.htm&type=5)

> When deleting a large number of contacts, the delete process can
>   contain no more than one million records.

Comment: Yes, but we want to delete the bulk record at a time.

Comment: I've updated my response accordinaly..

Answer (score 1):

You can automate the deletion process using SSJS. You need to populate a sendable data extension with Contact Keys you wish to delete (max 1 million at a time) and execute the call to Contact Deletion Framewok API. I have provided the code to do so, in my reply in this thread: [Marketing Cloud SSJS: trying to automate contact deletion](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/245799/36623)

Comment: How to create a sendable data extension for All Contacts (under contact builder) as we can not query all contacts?

Comment: If you don't have your contact keys stored elsewhere (i.e. outside of SFMC) and your contacts have not been emails (i.e. they are not in all subscribers list), there is no way of querying or exporting them. I would suggest you to reach out to support, and ask them to provide you with a CSV file with all your contact keys on SFMC FTP, from where you could import it into a sendable DE.