# Delete contacts through rest api

Tags: marketing-cloud, contact, ssjs, automationstudio, contact-deletion

I am trying to automate the deletion of contacts based on a data extension.
I am using this script but it keeps giving me the error "ERROR:  Error has occurred".

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

```
<script runat=server>
Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");

var authEndpoint = 'https://mc7zwyxpz1ynzspkkplqgk0dm798.rest.marketingcloudapis.com';
var payload = 
{
    client_id: "xxxx",
    client_secret: "yyyy",
    grant_type: "client_credentials",
    scope: "list_and_subscribers_write"
};


var url = authEndpoint + '/v2/token';  
var contentType = 'application/json';

try {
   var accessTokenRequest = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, Stringify(payload));
   if(accessTokenRequest.StatusCode == 200) {
        var tokenResponse = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(accessTokenRequest.Response[0]);
        var accessToken = tokenResponse.access_token;
   }
} catch (error) {
    Write(Stringify(error));
}

var deKey = 'C357F4A6-8C96-4812-B659-87A3F2F7E827';
var contentType = 'application/json';
var restUrl = tokenResponse.rest_instance_url;
var headerNames = ["Authorization"];
var headerValues = ["Bearer " + accessToken];

payload =  '{';
payload += '   "deleteOperationType": "ContactAndAttributes",';
payload += '   "targetList": { ';
payload += '      "listType": { ';
payload += '         "listTypeID":3';
payload += '      },';
payload += '   "listKey": "' + deKey + '"';
payload += '   },';
payload += '   "deleteListWhenCompleted":false,';
payload += '   "deleteListContentsWhenCompleted":true';
payload += '}';

var endpoint = restUrl + 'contacts/v1/contacts/actions/delete?type=listReference';

var result = HTTP.Post(endpoint, contentType, payload, headerNames, headerValues)
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most probably using a newly created credential package together with legacy endpoints. The auth endpoint needs to be updated to v2, as [described here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/access-token-s2s.htm). You will also see a difference in how token is provided in the response. Hence the parsing of this should be updated.

You should update this script to use tenant specific endpoint, replacing www.exacttargetapis.com with [yoursubdomain]. rest.marketingcloudapis.com as per [this article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_rn_october_2018_platform_tenant_specific_subdomains.htm&type=5).

Your snippet looks pretty much as my old code from [Trying to automate contact deletion with SSJS](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/245799/marketing-cloud-ssjs-trying-to-automate-contact-deletion) - and yes, I know it was deprecated. I have now updated the code to correspond to how the integration endpoints are implemented today.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I've updated my code based on your articles and it still isn't working. I've edited my post with the new code. Could you have a look?

Comment: There are multiple issues with your code (e.g. you don't use the correct url for AUTH endpoint). I have updated the code in my [old answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/245799/marketing-cloud-ssjs-trying-to-automate-contact-deletion) accordingly. Please use it for reference.

Comment: Thank you for updating your answer! I copied your code and changed the personal variables, it still isn't working :/.

Comment: @user3485470 - you need to perform this operation in root BU. also - did you even enable contact deletion as described [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_enable_contact_delete.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null)?

Comment: Yeah I've been doing it on the root BU and yes I have it enabled. I'll just log a case.

Comment: Let me know the resolution of the case you submitted, @user3485470 as it would be good to know if I have missed something obvious. One more advice, though. You should try running the script in a Cloud Page instead - as it will catch the error and print out the error message.

Comment: There was a missing } at the end of your code. The script runs fine now in automation studio. It didn't the delete the record though.

Comment: Thanks :-) I will fix the paranthesis. The deletion happens asynchronously, and you can monitor the status under Contact Builder > Contacts Analytics, where all the contact deletion requests are shown. Once you can see a request is processed successfully, your record should be gone.

Comment: Also, @user3485470 - do remember to accept/upvote if my answer has been helpful

Comment: This is the error message I am getting by the way: 
Exception Error: {"message":"An error occurred when attempting to evaluate a HTTPPost function call. See inner exception for details.","description":"ExactTarget.OMM.FunctionExecutionException: An error occurred when attempting to evaluate a HTTPPost function call. See inner exception for details.\r\n Error Code: OMM_FUNC_EXEC_ERROR\r\n - from Jint --> \r\n\r\n --- inner exception 1---\r\n\r\nSystem.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. - from System\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n"}