# Is there a function or an Api that allows me to remove a user from all existing Data extensions?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, ssjs, cloudpage

According to Habeas Data law, when a user wants to revoke the authorization to receive communications, we must not keep user information in any Data Extension, so we need to look for a user record in all Data Extensions to delete all their information, is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use contact deletion framework to remove a specific contact/subscriber key from all sendable data extensions. In order to do so (as per [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_delete_contact.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null)):

1. Navigate to All Contacts in Contact Builder.
2. Select the checkbox next to the contact. Click the bin symbol, and select **Delete selected contact**.

Or alternatively- use the [API route](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/DeleteByContactKeys.htm)

You might need to [enable contact deletion](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_contact_deletion.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null), if above step is not available.

Do also take a look on [this Trailhead module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/contact-deletion-in-marketing-cloud) about contact deletion.

It is also possible to [automate contact deletion](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/245799/trying-to-automate-contact-deletion-with-ssjs/245804#245804), if you need to do it on regular basis.

Comment: As a note this is only sendable DEs and allsubs/all contacts. Any non sendable DEs will retain their info