# Contact Deletion in Automation Studio with SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, ssjs, automationstudio, httppost

Basing on the article [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/245799/trying-to-automate-contact-deletion-with-ssjs) I prepared a code snippet to run in Automation Studio. Unfortunately we receive Bad Request(400) error for second API call everytime even though all passed parameters are correct.
The API call works perfectly fine in Postman.

Is there anything wrong with passing parameters into HTTP.Post?

```
SET @RowCount = RowCount(LookupRows("ENT.DU_DataExtensionforDeletionMapping","Type","DataExtension"))
SET @RowSet = LookupRows("ENT.DU_DataExtensionforDeletionMapping","Type", "DataExtension")
SET @counter = 1

IF (@RowCount > 0) THEN
FOR @counter = 1 to @RowCount DO /* repeat in a loop for as many times as defined in rowCount */ 
set @row = row(@RowSet, @counter) /* get row based on counter */ 
SET @DEExternalKey = FIELD(@row, "DEExternalKey")

SET @RowCountDeletion = DataExtensionRowCount(@DEExternalKey)
IF (@RowCountDeletion != 0) THEN

]%%-->

<script runat="server" language="JavaScript" executioncontexttype="get">
Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");

     //AUTHENTICATE
    var url = "https://xxxx.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/token";
    var contentType = "application/json";
    var payload1 =
        '{"grant_type": "client_credentials","client_id": "xxxx","client_secret": "xxxx","account_id":"xxxx"}';
    var accessTokenResult = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, payload1);
    var accessToken = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(accessTokenResult["Response"][0]).access_token;  

if (accessToken != "") {
        //EXECUTE
  var deKey = Variable.GetValue("@DEExternalKey");  
  var payload =  '{';
payload += '   "deleteOperationType": "ContactAndAttributes",';
payload += '   "targetList": { ';
payload += '      "listType": { ';
payload += '         "listTypeID":3';
payload += '      },';
payload += '   "listKey": "' + deKey + '"';
payload += '   },';
payload += '   "deleteListWhenCompleted":false,';
payload += '   "deleteListContentsWhenCompleted":true';
payload += '}';      

  var restUrl = 'https://xxxx.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/';
var headerNames = ["Authorization"];
var headerValues = ["Bearer " + accessToken];
          
var endpoint = restUrl + 'contacts/v1/contacts/actions/delete?type=listReference';  
  
  try {
var result = HTTP.Post(endpoint, contentType, payload, headerNames, headerValues);

        } catch (ex) {
            Write("Exception Error: " + Stringify(ex));
        }}

</script>


<!--%%[
ENDIF
SET @DateAdded = FIELD(@row, "DateAdded")
SET @RowCount2 = RowCount(LookupRows("ENT.DataExtensionsForDeletion","Type","Completed"))
SET @RowCount2 = ADD(@RowCount2, @counter)
SET @TargetRowCount = DataExtensionRowCount(@DEExternalKey)
InsertDE('ENT.DataExtensionsForDeletion','DEExternalKey' , @DEExternalKey,'NumberOfEntries', @TargetRowCount, "Type","Completed", "DateDeleted", NOW(1), "ID", @RowCount2, "DateAdded", @DateAdded)
NEXT
ENDIF
```