# How many SFMC contacts can be deleted in one REST call?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, contact-deletion

Specifically for the delete type "by key" or "by id" as outlined in the documentation:
[POST /contacts/v1/contacts/actions/delete?type=keys](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/DeleteByContactKeys.htm)

Wasn't finding any specific documentation on the matter but maybe looking in the wrong spots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best method for mass deletion of contacts is by using the [Delete by list reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/DeleteByListReference.htm) method, which allows you to delete batches of up to a million records at a time:

> When deleting from a sendable data extension, the call limits each
> process to one million rows.

You can read more about automating contact deletion in my answer to this question:

[Trying to automate contact deletion with SSJS](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/245799/trying-to-automate-contact-deletion-with-ssjs)

Comment: This information and links are a gold mine -- thank you. Although I was looking specifically for the limitations on the REST call for deleting by KEY or ID, which was not clear in the question. I am looking for ongoing deletion (daily) and not mass deletion.