# What contacts can be deleted in contact builder to reduce the contacts' count in Salesforce Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, contactbuilder

The count of "All contacts" has increased suddenly after integrating new business unit with sandbox. It is not possible to query all contacts, so what can be done to reduce the count of contacts? What all contacts can be deleted and how?

Answer (score 0):

You should look for contacts with no channel address. They can be found using a specific data extract in your enterprise business unit, where you can store the output in a data extension, and use it to perform an automated contact deletion, as I have described here: [Trying to automate contact deletion with SSJS](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/245799/trying-to-automate-contact-deletion-with-ssjs/245804#245804)

Contacts Without Channel Addresses is an available extract type that doesn’t require support to activate the feature. Unlike other data extracts, this type outputs directly to a data extension. The process for extracting the data is following

- When configuring the data extract, the File Naming Pattern field is required. But it doesn’t control the output of data from the extract or the naming pattern of the data extension.
- Add any File Naming Pattern to the Contacts Without Channel Address extract configuration.
- Create an FTP user if one doesn’t yet exist. Otherwise, you receive an error message when starting the data extract.
- The Contacts Without Channel Address data extension is located under the root data extension folder.
- The process takes several hours to run.
- Run this extract at the Enterprise ID level.
- You can’t run the process more than one time in a 24-hour period.
- If you had a productive run in the last 24 hours, you can submit the request and report success. No processing occurs and the contents of the data extension where the contacts are extracted remain unchanged.

You can find all these details [in the documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_cab_contacts_without_channel_address.htm&type=5).

Prior to running the contact deletion, you must ensure your sandbox integration is provided with a filter, so you avoid reintroducing same number of contacts into your SFMC instance once more.