# Marketing Cloud subscribers massive delete

Tags: marketing-cloud, delete, subscriber

I am trying to delete all the subscribers from the "All subscribers" list but it only allows me the option to delete by parts or one by one.

I thought that I could do an overrite by importing a file or by automatism, but this idea has also been discarded.

In cases of having 1 million subscribers I think there should be a simpler way to do it.

Comment: Please refer to this thread :
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/245799/trying-to-automate-contact-deletion-with-ssjs