# How to Contact delete (All contacts) in Child BU

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, ssjs, automationstudio, contact-deletion

Is there a way to do contact delete in Child BU? (All contacts)

I want to delete the Contact in bulk.

All marketing activities (Journey, e-mail sending, etc.) take place in Child BU.

I would like to delete the contact generated by marketing activities in Child BU from Child BU.

If there is no way to delete it from Child BU, I would appreciate it if you could also tell me how to delete Contact from Parent BU.

Please let me know how I can automate it using Automation studio such as query, SSJS, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Contact Deletion would need to be performed in the Parent BU context.

You can [manually delete contacts](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_cab_delete_contact.htm&type=5) from Contact Builder in the Parent BU.

To run it in an Automation, you would need to rely on MC REST APIs. Check this [Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/DeleteByListReference.html) for the Contact Deletion REST API.

Although you'd need the OAuth credentials to be able to call the API and write it in SSJS for the Script Activity for your automation. Check this [Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/access-token-s2s.html) for the Access token.

Above information is not a full solution but clues so you can research and can solve it by yourself.

Comment: I turned the automation to the ssjs 
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/245799/trying-to-automate-contact-deletion-with-ssjs

and it says Complete but the Contact is not deleted. Is there an error with the ssjs or is there a way to delete the Contact in bulk any other way?

Comment: I am not sure exactly how you did but it should work with the REST API

Comment: @SeungilShin it can take some time for the contacts to be deleted. Especially when talking about deleting them in large bulks. Allow few hours after you have executed the ssjs and check again.